# I want to update specific textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I have some database results, I populate them in form, I have this code:

```
<input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript: addQty();' value='+'/>
<span><?php echo $records['ct_qty']; ?></span>
<input type="text" class="gridder_input" name="quant[]" class="quant" id="quant[]" />
<input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript: subtractQty();' value='-'/>
```

So I want to update specific row when the user presses the "quant" button:

```
function addQty() {
    document.getElementById("quant").value++;
}

function subtractQty() {
    if (document.getElementById("quant").value - 1 < 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("quant").value--;
    }
    updateQuantity();
}
```

This code works when I have one row, when I have 2 or more rows nothing works, so I probably have to use this word or something?

Comment: Could you setup demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: how can i update there mysql results?

Comment: You could give example data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i dont have a good enough example of your code, but this should be enough to get you in the right direction...

```js
function getTotals() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var quant = table.rows[i].querySelector('input[name="quant"]').value;
    var priceoriginal = table.rows[i].querySelector('input[name="priceoriginal"]').value;
    table.rows[i].querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = quant * priceoriginal;


  }

}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="quant" type="text" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="priceoriginal" type="text" value="6">
    </td>
    <td>Total:
      <input name="total" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="quant" type="text" value="8">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="priceoriginal" type="text" value="4">
    </td>
    <td>Total:
      <input name="total" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="quant" type="text" value="5">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="priceoriginal" type="text" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>Total:
      <input name="total" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="getTotals()">Calculate Totals</button>
```

Comment: @perastikos1 no problem. Please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can target the neare input using the sibling selectors.

```js
function addQty(elm) {
  elm.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.value++;
}

function subtractQty(elm) {
  if (elm.previousElementSibling.value - 1 < 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    elm.previousElementSibling.value--;
  }
  updateQuantity();
}
```

```html
<input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript: addQty(this);' value='+' />
<span><?php echo $records['ct_qty']; ?></span>
<input type="text" class="gridder_input" name="quant[]" class="quant" id="quant[]" />
<input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript: subtractQty(this);' value='-' />
```